# Serialize objects that contain utf-8 strings

Tags: php, serialization

How can I serialize objects with fields that contain utf8 strings?

Now i get back false after `unserialize`.

Comment: this is from C# and Java. are any of the fields read-only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't care what values strings contain when you use serialize/unserialize. Can you provide a code example to demonstrate this problem

Has the class definition been included at the point when you try to unserialize?

Comment: Then it was a problem when I wanted to save one attribute of an object, that contains htmlsource, but when I not wrote into the __sleep function is worked.
but when I wrote into the __sleep function is not worked.
I do not know why!

Comment: Please provide code example... you should only need to use the __sleep() method if you're only serializing some attributes of the object, or have additional processing requirements on serialize

Comment: If you only want to serialize one attribute, then why not simply serialize that one attribute rather than the whole object?